# Send an email based on search inputs

Tags: email, supersearch, postmaster

Looking at building a search form which sends an email alert to a members based on search terms eg: membership level/location/custom fields/tags/categories. In addition I need to send an additional email to other EE member's after 24 & 72 hours depending on level of membership and if they also match the search criteria.

I have looked at Postmaster & Super Search but not 100% sure if I will be able to do all of this. Is it possible just using Postmaster or should something custom be built here?

Comment: You'll have an incoming answer if you can clean up your question a little. Does the search trigger the email, or do you want a 'send an email' button next to each result? Etc... A little more clarity will help me help you!

Comment: Sorry, yes the search will trigger the email and send to members who fit the search criteria